# orientations in n dimensional tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have a $n$-dimensional tensor. I am working with this tensor in $n$ different orientations. For example in 3d, a 3d tensor can be represented in three different orientations or directions. Is there a specific terminology for these tensors with different orientations?

Comment: do you know what are the orientations in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: orientation in R^2 means through x axis and y axis. X orientation means I take the matrix in the direction of x. For example: If I have a matrix [1 2; 3 4] where x axis is horizontal and y axis is vertical. Then the matrix in x orientation would be [1 3; 2 4] and the matrix in the y orientation would be [1 2; 3 4].

Comment: respectfully:  from where (or who) do you take this? can you give us references?

Comment: I didnot take it from any reference. I am working with tensors. I have a n mode tensor. I want to represent this tensor from all the directions. I think the word orientation would not be appropriate here. But basicly what i am saying is if A is a tendor of 4 mode then A[i,:,:,:], A[:,i,:,:], A[:,:,i,:],A[:,:,:,i] is what i am referring to as tensor A from 4 different orientations (4 bases direction)

Comment: orientation and direction are not appropriate terminologies. I am looking for appropriate mathematical terminologies for these.